# send tx with smartcontract and self destruction

Tags: selfdestruct

help me, I want to create a smart contract with the function send internal tx then self destruct
like this example

this hash address polygon
[txhash](https://polygonscan.com/tx/0x37c9dc74716b41f8dd6447d154c904bc342521e06e3e39f00a80a4a1afdf0d7f)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Basically, as you can notice in the transaction Logs, the MATIC is sent to recipient (0xe6...) by the msg.sender as msg.sender -> contract -> recipient: Here is the completed code

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract SendAndSelfDestruct {
    address payable public recipient;

    event EtherSentAndSelfDestructed(address indexed sender, address indexed recipient, uint256 amount);

    constructor(address payable _recipient) {
        recipient = _recipient;
    }

    receive() external payable {}

    function sendEtherAndSelfDestruct() public {
        require(msg.sender != recipient, "Sender cannot be the recipient");
        uint256 amountToSend = address(this).balance; // Send the entire balance to the recipient

        // Send Ether to the recipient
        require(recipient.send(amountToSend), "Failed to send Ether");

        // Self-destruct the contract
        selfdestruct(payable(msg.sender));

        // Emit an event
        emit EtherSentAndSelfDestructed(msg.sender, recipient, amountToSend);
    }
}
```

Then, in your external code to call function sendEtherAndSelfDestruct, you should put the value (Ether) in the transaction. Some thing similar to this:

```
    txn = contract.functions.sendEtherAndSelfDestruct().buildTransaction({
        'from': owner,
        'value': 100000000, # fix the value you want
        'gasPrice': web3.toWei('15', 'gwei'),
        'nonce': web3.eth.get_transaction_count(owner),
    })
```

Hope it helps!!